# Read an mp3's metadata

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to read an mp3's metadata using javascript for playing with the  element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, and I was suprised to see you can!
http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/reading-id3-tags-with-javascript.html

There is source code and examples on that page.