# HTML5 audio element audio data

Tags: javascript, html, dom, audio

Is there any way I can see the audio data of a certain audio tag? where I can see what key is it in, and how many its BPM(beats per minute) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to figure out the key or BPM, audio files are blind to that kind of information, so you'll have to write an algorithm to do that yourself. If you want other types of metadata, perhaps see [Read an mp3's metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063419/read-an-mp3s-metadata)

Comment: I suppose reading the music file in-browser would be done with the Web Audio API, though I don't know how that works.